# Change some value in _layout.cshtml when display a view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Is there a way to change some parts (some values) in the _layout.cshml when I return a View or PartialView ? I'd like display the view or partial view AND change some values in the _layout.cshtml

In the `_layout.cshtml` :

```
<div id="#mydiv"></div>
```

In the controller :

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var model = new MyModel();
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: There are plenty of way to change values, how about some example code and a description of what and when you want your "values" to change.

Comment: Plenty .... give me one it's enought :) I updated the question.

Comment: @DaveA Could you explain a little bit more ?

Answer (score 1):

Sections are placeholders in your `_Layout` that can be populated by your View:

Example:

```
<div id="navBar">
  @RenderSection("navBar", required: false)
</div>
```

would have a corresponding section in your View

```
@section navBar 
  {

    @if (Model.needsNavBar==true)
    {

        //navBar code
    }


  }
```

If it's not obvious, whatever markup goes in your View's section definition is rendered in your `_Layout`. The importance of `required: false` is your page will run without error if your section definition is left out of your View.

Comment: Can we use the model on the @section ?

Comment: @Kris-I sure. Use the Model anyway you like. It's just like creating markup in your View, except it's rendered in your Layout's Section area. (does that make sense?)

Comment: Can I ask you one more question ?

Comment: @Kris-I, did the answer help you?

Answer (score 0):

OK since you won't be specific lets consider a scenario

you had some data that you want on every page lets define it

```
// pretend it comes from your database or where ever
var somedata = Guid.NewGuid();
```

how are we going to get this in the navbar of our Layout

Well in EVERY controller actionmethod you could do this

```
 public ActionResult Index(AssessorSearchRecordSearchViewModel model)
 {
  ViewBag.SomeData = Guid.NewGuid(); 
  return View();
 }
```

and then show it in your view in a heading with

```
 <h1>@ViewBag.SomeData</h1>
```

but that would be annoying to do and it brittle to change

You could create a baseclass for your controller

```
public abstract class AppBaseController : Controller
{
    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);            
        ViewBag.SomeData = Guid.NewGuid(); 
    }

}
```

and this would make it available in all action methods

So that's one example but there are literally dozens of ways to make data available.